# How to remove unused imports with a command?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have files in my `nx` project with import declaration without any use and I want to remove them.

After I searched in stackoverflow I found the answer to open the file in vscode, and press `alt+shift+o` and when the declaration is not used then it's remove and sort the import.

But I have 10,000 files. so is there a command to do that in all those files? I looking in `eslint` but there is no rule for that.

Comment: have you tried this plugin? https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unused-imports

Comment: duplicate candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970457/organise-imports-for-all-files-in-project/55970626

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the [no-unused-imports plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unused-imports)

Add unused-imports to the plugins section of your .eslintrc file

```
{
  "plugins": ["...", "unused-imports"]
}
```

add the following rules

```
"no-unused-vars": "off",
"unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
"unused-imports/no-unused-vars": [
  "warn",
  { "vars": "all", "varsIgnorePattern": "^_", "args": "after-used", "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ],
```

Then add script to your package.json file

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "fix-lint-errors": "eslint nx --fix"
},
```

from command line run the script

```
npm run fix-lint-errors
```

or

```
yarn fix-lint-errors
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a heavy [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) user, so you can simply open your preference settings then add the following to your settings.json:

```json
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    }
```

Or you can make a stand alone [tslint](/questions/tagged/tslint) file that has the following in it:

```
{
    "extends": ["tslint-etc"],
    "rules": {
            "no-unsed-declaration: true"
}}
```

Then run the following command to fix the imports:

```
tslint --config tslint-imports.json --fix --project
```

Then use

```
ng build
```

or

```
ng build name_of_project --configuration=production
```